# How to best manage public and private sets of source code?

Tags: svn, git, version-control

I have(ie, "own") an open source project that I want to do some work on and extend and then sell it. The problem comes down to managing it all in source control though. My open source project has SVN. This repo is publicly accessible. What would be the best way to make a secondary (private) repository, but keep these two sets of source code fairly in-sync?

The only way I can figure so far is just using creating and applying patches between the two. But that seems tedious at best. I'm thinking that Git might be able to do this good, but I'm unexperienced in Git, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't use svn for distributed version control...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using Git instead of SVN. With Git you can merge between separate repositories and branches easily. You can find a great guide [here](http://progit.org/book/). For example, if you were to host your code on [github.com](https://github.com/) you could create a private repository for your own code and a public one for the open source project. You could then merge between the two repositories locally without having to create patches and apply them to each branch. Git is fast, so creating and destroying branches is easy and has little overhead. It is created with this workflow in mind and there is a great community available to answer your questions should you get stuck.

Comment: One question, to be compatible with my opensource hosting provider, would it be possible to use git-svn for such a scenario?

Comment: Absolutely, but it's just going to be a little more work on your end to support both SCM systems because you'll need to familiarize yourself with git-svn. I would recommend creating a remote private git repository that you can use in conjunction with your public svn repository. Of course you could always switch providers from an SVN provider to a Git provider :)

Comment: well, the provider does support Git, but I'm not quite wanting to switch just yet in case I just really hate Git

Comment: That makes sense. I think git-svn is a great option for you then. It's also easy to experiment with git, so you can make a copy of your current SVN repository and host it with git and try it out. You can also have SVN and Git live together on your local machine and simply have them ignore each-other's config files, but I would recommend git-svn over this approach.